# How to get elasticsearch suggestions working on multiple fields from multiple types?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement to have a search box globally on the website that user can type anything in, a bit like google. As the user is typing along, he should get suggestions. I have multiple types in an Index, I am using Completion suggester to get suggestions from one field like below:

```
GET /index/_suggest/
{
    "person-suggest" : {
"text" : "m",
"completion" : {
    "field" : "nameSuggest"
    }
  }
}
```

The requirement is such that when they type a person name which is stored in person type or type in a company name which is stored in company type...both suggestions should appear. Also, within the same type, it should be able to suggest based on multiple fields not just one like what I've got. And finally once the user selects a suggestion, do a search and show facets which are based on multiple types.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-type suggestions on multiple fields, use-

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/indexName/type1,type2/_suggest' -d '{
  "my-suggestion-1" : {
    "text" : "some text",
    "term" : {
      "field" : "field1"
    }
  },
"my-suggestion-2" : {
    "text" : "some text",
    "term" : {
      "field" : "field2"
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks....yeah, I saw this but not too happy about this as I have about 15 types and at least 3-5 searchable fields in each type, request body will be huge.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar Then you need to change your design. What else were you expecting? There has to be a way to tell Elasticsearch which type and which field you want suggestions for. And what exactly is your concern about the "huge" request body?

Comment: @bittusarkar Thanks for your comment. I was hoping if it was possible to send field an array instead of a single field.

Comment: @have you figured this out. Is there is a way to pass multiple fields to the phrase suggester ?